# jQuery dynamic solution for boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following website (check my attachment), which has 4 boxes. All boxes will be enabled when a specific status is being activated.

[image]

In this example I have the following statusses:
- 1.1 = (first 1 stands for box 1, second digit stands for: Which background I want to activate red (digit: 0) or green (digit: 1). In my example I have the green box activated. Like: `addClass('list-group-item-success');` (digit 1) and `addClass('list-group-item-warning');` (digit 0)

What I want is to to this for all boxes. Example: If my systems pushes status: 3.1, then I want the system to colour the background from box 1 till 3 (green, sucess).

Another example: If status is: 4.0. Then all boxes 1 till 3 needs to be coloured green (success) and the 4th box need to be red (class danger).

How is this possible?

Current HTML

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="" id="psLoggedIn" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start disabled">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1"><strong>Voorgemeld</strong> <span id="psStatusLoggedIn" class="badge"></span></h5>
      <small id="psSignLoggedIn" class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Uw pakket is aangemeld bij de vervoerder en is bekend.</p>
    <small id="psInfoLoggedIn"></small>
  </a>
  <a href="" id="psDepot" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start disabled">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1"><strong>In depot</strong> <span id="psStatusDepot" class="badge"></span></h5>
      <small id="psSignDepot" class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Zending bevindt zich in een centraal depot. Zending wordt gesorteerd naar uw regio.</p>
    <small id="psInfoDepot"></small>
  </a>
  <a href="" id="psInTransit" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start disabled">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1"><strong>Onderweg</strong> <span id="psStatusInTransit" class="badge"></span></h5>
      <small id="psSignInTransit" class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Zending is onderweg voor aflevering op uw adres.</p>
    <small id="psInfoInTransit"></small>
  </a>
  <a href="" id="psDelivered" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start disabled">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1"><strong>Geleverd</strong> <span id="psStatusDelivered" class="badge"></span></h5>
      <small id="psSignDelivered" class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Zending is geleverd</p>
    <small id="psInfoDelivered"></small>
  </a>
</div>
```

jQuery: (This does not work at all, as it is only colouring box 1 ofcourse).

```
if (shipmentStatusCodeSecond == '1') {

  if (shipmentStatusCodeFirst => '1') {

    $('#psStatusLoggedIn').html('Succesvol');
    $('#psStatusLoggedIn').addClass('badge-success')
    $('#psLoggedIn').addClass('list-group-item-success');
    $('#psLoggedIn').removeClass('disabled')

  } else if (shipmentStatusCodeFirst == '2' || shipmentStatusCodeFirst == '3' || shipmentStatusCodeFirst == '4') {

    $('#psStatusDepot').html('Succesvol');
    $('#psStatusDepot').addClass('badge-success')
    $('#psDepot').addClass('list-group-item-success');
    $('#psDepot').removeClass('disabled');

  } else if (shipmentStatusCodeFirst == '3' || shipmentStatusCodeFirst == '4') {
    $('#psStatusInTransit').html('Succesvol');
    $('#psStatusInTransit').addClass('badge-success')
    $('#psInTransit').addClass('list-group-item-success');
    $('#psInTransit').removeClass('disabled');

  } else if (shipmentStatusCodeFirst == '4') {
    $('#psStatusDelivered').html('Succesvol');
    $('#psStatusDelivered').addClass('badge-success')
    $('#psDelivered').addClass('list-group-item-success');
    $('#psDelivered').removeClass('disabled');
  }
}
```

Comment: Show how you store/retrieve the data for multiple boxes. Is it an array or a delimited string?

Comment: As my example jQuery, that is all what I do. That is the whole problem, I am been thinking about this for hours how to do this (writing it out on paper) but clear it out for my self.

PS. My HTML is just fixed as you see, with different ID's for each part. It it very important that those 4 boxes, will be always visible.

Comment: Replace `shipmentStatusCodeFirst => '1'` with `shipmentStatusCodeFirst >= '1'`

Comment: you need either an object or array to store the status  for multiple boxes. Then loop over the object or array and update the associated box

Comment: charlietfl, Is it possible to show me how to do this with a code? So I understand what happens.

Comment: Other thing is, from my DB I get the status (example): 3.1 - the only thing that jQuery needs to do is colouring.

Comment: You can do lot's of refactor in the code, like repeating the code instead you can write like `$(selector).eq(yourfirstcode).removeClass('badge-success').addClass('badge-success')` here some corner condition are require but this is how you can achieve the requirement with minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is maybe not beautiful, but it works and the actual code is fairly short:

```js
var steps=$('a div.d-flex','.list-group'); // collect the divs to be colored ...
$('input#code').keyup(function(){var fld,col;
  [fld,col]=$(this).val().split('.');  // parse code into fld and col
                                       // only step into action for valid codes ...
  if (fld>0&&fld<5&&(col==='0'||col==='1')){
    // first: remove all "success" and "warning" classes 
    steps.removeClass('list-group-item-success list-group-item-warning')
    // then: assign success to all but the last step
         .slice(0,fld-1).addClass('list-group-item-success');  
    // assign the last step ("warning" or "success", according to col)
    steps.eq(fld-1).addClass('list-group-item-'+['warning','success'][col]);        
  }
})
```

```css
.list-group-item-success {background-color:#cfc}
.list-group-item-warning {background-color:#fcc}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="code" placeholder="enter code here"/><br>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="" id="psLoggedIn" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start disabled">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1"><strong>Voorgemeld</strong> <span id="psStatusLoggedIn" class="badge"></span></h5>
      <small id="psSignLoggedIn" class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Uw pakket is aangemeld bij de vervoerder en is bekend.</p>
    <small id="psInfoLoggedIn"></small>
  </a>
  <a href="" id="psDepot" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start disabled">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1"><strong>In depot</strong> <span id="psStatusDepot" class="badge"></span></h5>
      <small id="psSignDepot" class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Zending bevindt zich in een centraal depot. Zending wordt gesorteerd naar uw regio.</p>
    <small id="psInfoDepot"></small>
  </a>
  <a href="" id="psInTransit" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start disabled">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1"><strong>Onderweg</strong> <span id="psStatusInTransit" class="badge"></span></h5>
      <small id="psSignInTransit" class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Zending is onderweg voor aflevering op uw adres.</p>
    <small id="psInfoInTransit"></small>
  </a>
  <a href="" id="psDelivered" data-toggle="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start disabled">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1"><strong>Geleverd</strong> <span id="psStatusDelivered" class="badge"></span></h5>
      <small id="psSignDelivered" class="text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Zending is geleverd</p>
    <small id="psInfoDelivered"></small>
  </a>
</div>
```